# htacess redirect to paths and remaining ones to domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I am trying to redirect some domain paths to new ones.
This is what i have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Redirect permanent /old.html    https://www.new.com/new
...

....
```

That ones work fine.
Since we do not cover all paths, I added a line at the end for the remaining ones:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.new.com/xxxx/yyyyy/ [R=301,L]
```

That last one, doesn't work.
What is wrong with it?

My goal is, to redirect all that are listed in the htacess, for the non listed ones, i want the general redirect.

Many Thanks

Comment: you want to redirect any uri like /abc/  to new.com/xxxx/yyyyy/abc or only new.com/xxxx/yyyyy/ also is new.com different domain name ?

Comment: Try using a new browser for testing as it might be a caching issue.